# How to construct an intent object with a subclass of the defined class?

Tags: java, android, oop

I want to have a function to build and start an activity of certain class and its subclass, let say I have two activity `A` and `B`

```
public class A extends AppCompatActivity {...}

public class B extends A {...}
```

I have a function in MainActivity called `startAActivity()`

```
private void startAActivity(Object someExtra, Class<A> activityClass) {
  Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.class, activityClass);
  i.putExtra(SOME_EXTRA, someExtra);
  startActivity(i);
}
```

if I call `startAActivity(extra, B.class)` I will get an error because it is expecting the Class object of class A, I know I can just put a `?` in the function signature to make it work, but since B is a subclass of A, is there a way that I can keep the parameter as `Class<A> activityClass` so that `Class<B>` will be treated as `Class<A>`? Just for more Polymorphism?

Comment: why do you want to do so?

Comment: create helper function for more polymorphism? I want this function to only start activity of class A and its subclass, please read question more carefully

Comment: Alex, What you want to do Works better if you Create Classes A and B Separate. Let each Class be Unique.

Comment: @Shahin, it is because B almost have the same functionality of A but some extra one, I don't think the reason of why they have inheritance related to the question...

Comment: I know tried to do this, but there are better ways to use the same codes at a certain time, have you looked into Activity Life cycles? OnStart(), OnPause(), On destroy(). I think you can do the same way Easier.

Comment: I also think If Activity B is the same as A, well that means you don't have to need it. You absolutely have other ways to do this

Comment: @Shahin, no they are not the same...they are almost the same but B have some additional functionality, so it is best to make B a subclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your second parameter type `Class<A>` to `Class<? extends A>`

```
private void startAActivity(Object someExtra, Class<? extends A> activityClass) {
  Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.class, activityClass);
  i.putExtra(SOME_EXTRA, someExtra);
  startActivity(i);
}
```